# React Context API's setters work very slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, react-context

My goal is to make such a functionality as changing the background gradient of the page depending on is child's sublinks are expanded/collapsed. For this I'm using useContext hook, but I noticed that even though everything is working as expected, the background gradient does change, but it takes ~20s for it to rerender the sublinks that were collapsed/expanded. I've seen only one question on SO with the same problem, but I didn't really understand how to solve it. The problem is that all children of context provider get rerendered because of state in context changing.
I'd upload a codesandbox example, but I was asked not to, so here're the most reproducible code snippets. How can I use that functionality and prevent the children from rerendering, so everything works faster? Help please :)

```
const Wrapper = styled('div')<{linksExpanded : boolean}>`
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 0.2%, #FFFFFF 3%);
  background-color: white;
  ${({theme})=>theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 1.5%, #FFFFFF 5.5%);
  }
  ${({linksExpanded , theme})=>linksExpanded && `
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 2.5%, #FFFFFF 4.25%);
    ${theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
      background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 6.5%, #FFFFFF 10%);
    }
  `}
`

const Home = () =>
{
  const { linksExpanded } = useContext(HomeDataContext);
  return (
            <Wrapper linksExpanded={linksExpanded}>
              <About />
              <Links />
              <Contacts />
              <Gallery />
            </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const Landing: FC = () => <PageSkeleton
        pageContent={
          <HomeDataContextProvider><Home /></HomeDataContextProvider>}
      />;


const Links = () => {
  const { currentCakes, linksExpanded, setLinksExpanded } = useContext(HomeDataContext);
  const renderLinks = () => (
    <S.List style={{maxHeight: !linksExpanded ? '0px' : '1000px'}}>
      {currentCakes.map((el: CakeDescription, key : number) => (
        <li key={el.name}>
          <a href='https://google.com'>Link</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </S.List>
  );
  const handleLinksExpand = () => {
    setLinksExpanded(!linksExpanded);
  };
  return (
    <S.Container>
        <S.ExpandableLinkContainer>
          <ExpandableLink
            onClick={handleLinksExpand}
            open={linksExpanded}
            title='Cakes'
          />
        </S.ExpandableLinkContainer>
        {renderLinks()}
    </S.Container>
  );
};
export default Links;
```

The Context finally:

```
export type HomeDataState = {
  currentCakes: Array<CakeDescription>;
  setCurrentCakes?: any;
  linksExpanded: boolean;
  setLinksExpanded?: any;
};

const initialValue: HomeDataState = {
  currentCakes: [],
  linksExpanded: false,
};

export const HomeDataContext = createContext(initialValue as HomeDataState);

export const HomeDataContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [linksExpanded, setLinksExpanded] = useState(initialValue.linksExpanded);
  const [currentCakes, setCurrentCakes] = useState<CakeDescription[]>(initialValue.cakes);
  const fetchCakes = async () => {
    setCurrCakes(
      await myAxiosConstruct.get(process.env.api);
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCakes();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <HomeDataContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentCakes,
        linksExpanded,
        setLinksExpanded,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </HomeDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Home` component is consuming the `HomeDataContext`, no matter what property is updated React will re-render the entire component, involving every children component (`Wrapper`, `About`, `Links`, `Contact`, `Gallery`) so it is the correct behaviour.

What we could do here is to separate Context in two: `LinksContext` and `CakesContext`, both with their respective Providers, and refactor the application as follows:

1. `renderLinks()` is now a component (`Cakes`) which will be only re-rendered if `currentCakes` is updated. Previously was being re-rendered on every state change.
2. By wrapping `Cakes` in `memo` we prevent the child re-rendering by React when `Home` updates.
3. We should use `memo` in both `Contacts` and `Gallery` components too in order to prevent the same re-render.

Give it a try, hope it helps you!
A complete explation of how to optimize and good practices can be found here: [React Context, All in One](https://dev.to/javmurillo/react-context-all-in-one-54ck)

```
const Wrapper = styled('div')<{linksExpanded : boolean}>`
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 0.2%, #FFFFFF 3%);
  background-color: white;
  ${({theme})=>theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 1.5%, #FFFFFF 5.5%);
  }
  ${({linksExpanded , theme})=>linksExpanded && `
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 2.5%, #FFFFFF 4.25%);
    ${theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
      background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, pink 6.5%, #FFFFFF 10%);
    }
  `}
`

export const Home = () =>
{
  const { linksExpanded, setLinksExpanded } = useContext(LinksContext);
  return (
            <Wrapper linksExpanded={linksExpanded}>
              <About />
              <Links linksExpanded={linksExpanded} setLinksExpanded={setLinksExpanded} />
              <Contacts />
              <Gallery />
            </Wrapper>
  );
};

export const Landing = () => <PageSkeleton
        pageContent={
          <HomeDataContextProvider>
            <Home />
          </HomeDataContextProvider>
        } />;

export const Cakes = memo(() => {
  const { currentCakes } = useContext(CakesContext)

  return currentCakes.map((el, key) => (
    <li key={el.name}>
      <a href='https://google.com'>Link</a>
    </li>
  ))
})

export const Links = ({ linksExpanded, setLinksExpanded }) => {
  const handleLinksExpand = () => {
    setLinksExpanded(!linksExpanded);
  };

  return (
    <S.Container>
        <S.ExpandableLinkContainer>
          <ExpandableLink
            onClick={handleLinksExpand}
            open={linksExpanded}
            title='Cakes'
          />
        </S.ExpandableLinkContainer>
        <S.List style={{maxHeight: !linksExpanded ? '0px' : '1000px'}}>
          <Cakes/>
        </S.List>
    </S.Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: That works perfect, thank you very much! And double thank you for the great explanation!